# Убрать тег, оставить его содержимое (unwrap)

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

Код на Ruby использует Nokogiri, обрабатывает HTML.
Нужно удалить лишние `<div class="section">`, оставив их содержимое. Структура такая:

```
<div class="section" id="a">
    <p>content</p>
    <div class="section" id="b">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="c">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="d">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Пробовал два варианта:

```
@html.xpath("//div[@class = 'section']").each do |div|
  div.parent.inner_html = div.inner_html unless div.parent.nil?
end

@html.xpath("//div[@class = 'section']").each do |div|
  div.replace(div.inner_html)
end
```

В обоих случаях удаляется только внешний `<div class="section">`, а вложенные остаются. Смотрел в логи: селектор Xpath находит все эти дивы, не только вложенный. Соответственно, и цикл проходит по всем.

Подозреваю, что после того, как заменяется первый `<div>`, дерево его содержимого выстраивается заново из `div.inner_html`. Поэтому остальные дивы уже находятся не в этом дереве, так что их замена ничего не даёт.

Вопрос: как заменить все?

Дополнительный вопрос: объясните, как именно происходит замена, почему вложенные дивы не заменяются?

Comment: Сделал рекурсивный перебор, он решает проблему, но по внутренним нодам проходит по два или больше раза. Всё ещё ищу решение за один проход.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать внешний цикл, который будет повторять итератор `@html.xpath("//div[@class = 'section']").each` до тех пор, пока он будет осуществлять хоть бы одну замену за проход. Соответственно, после каждого прохода внешнего цикла, итератор `@html.xpath("//div[@class = 'section']").each` будет находить всё более вложенные элементы, пока не исчерпается вложенность.

Кроме того, можно ограничиться изменением одного элемента за один проход внешнего цикла, выполняя выход из внутреннего итератора во внешний цикл после каждой успешной замены первого найденного элемента (тем самым пересоздавая внутренний итератор на основании измененной иерархии). При таком подходе можно пойти дальше и вообще отказаться от внутреннего итератора, заменив его на вызов `at_xpath`, который сразу же возвращает один найденный элемент.

Comment: Так всё равно получается, что за первый проход мы обрабатываем все четыре элемента, а за второй — b, c и d.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, судя по результату, обработка части элементов проходит как минимум не до конца (а возможно, вообще останавливается на этапе проверки **unless div.parent.nil?** - но это нужно проверить, это лишь предположение). Кроме того, совершенно не обязательно делать каждый проход полностью по всем элементам. Можно после успешной замены первого найденного элемента завершать работу внутреннего итератора и выходить во внешний цикл, чтобы пересоздавать внутренний итератор на основании обновленной иерархии и обработать следующий элемент.

Comment: Кроме того, можно вообще отказаться от внутреннего итератора и использовать **at_xpath** вместо **xpath** для нахождения одного элемента за каждый проход внешнего цикла.

Comment: Про `unless div.parent.nil` — там они все внутри `<body>`, так что, вроде, не должно быть пропусков. Ну и это первый вариант, а я остановился на втором и сделал в нём рекурсию.

Comment: Хм, а вот `at_xpath` выглядит интересно, попробую. Может, в ответ это добавите?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, логично. Уже добавил. Спасибо за совет.